# No colors inside a json-diff diffString output

Tags: json, diff

How can I specify colorizeOptions so I won't have color coding inside the output like "[32m+", "[39m-", etc.?

Currently I get something like this below:

```
 [
 ...
 {
 context: {
 }
   values: [
[32m+      {[39m
[32m+        itemCount: 2626[39m
[32m+        name: "WWE"[39m
 ...
 ...
 ...
 ...
 ...
 ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```javascript
jsonDiff.diffString(
  originalObject,
  changedObject,
  { color: "" }
)
```

works.

Setting `color: ""` doesn't put any color coding text inside the output.

Comment: What worked? How did it work? What made it work? Why did that make it work?

Comment: I'm not sure if they changed the contract, but it I think it should be `{ color: false }`

Comment: User *yalkris* may have left the building (*"Last seen more than a month ago"*)